# Automatic pressing of the key on the keyboard when the button on the interface is pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine

When the user presses the button on the interface, I want the 1 button to be pressed automatically, how can I do that?

Comment: Let me know if I'm wrong (it seems like the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). You have an action mapped to a particular key. You also want to trigger that action on a UI event ?

Comment: yes this is what i want to do

Comment: I didn't work with UIs for a long time, but as far as I know, you can specify a list of functions to call for each event of your UI element. Encapsulate the action in a function that will be call both on UI event, and in your script on button pressed.

Comment: so what you actually want is just call the same method via UI as via the button .... you don't really want to simulate the button press .. Please provide more context and your code in question ..

Comment: I searched for these but couldn't find an example how to do it